# Add a different number at the final of a regular expression

Tags: python, bash

I have a text and I want to add a number at the end of a regular expression that is repeated in the text. For example I have the expression "grep text" several times and I would like to become "grep text1", the next time when the expression appears in text file to become "grep text2"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where did you get stuck in accomplishing this? What's the question here? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I thought I was on unix.stack... :D

Comment: A regular expression alone can only *match* text. Many languages offer a substitution mechanism on top, but that's no longer strictly a regex topic, for Python, look at `re.sub()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Input file

```
grep test
grep test
grep test
```

### [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command

```
awk '/grep test/{c++; print $0c}' file
```

### Output

```
grep test1
grep test2
grep test3
```

Comment: That might be enough for OP's case, but it will fail if 'grep test' isn't alone on its line

Comment: I can't answer now that the question has been closed, but if that's a problem I would use `gawk '{ while (sub(/\<grep text\>/, "grep text" i) != 0) {i++} ; print $0 }'`. [Try it here](https://ideone.com/1PjVgP).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
you are great